# Azure Service Fabric activation error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-deployment

The deployment of one of my apps to a `Service Fabric Cluster` failed and triggered an Unhealthy Evaluation with an error event saying: `There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:3762504530`

However, on the node where the app is deployed, Health State indicates: `The application was activated successfully.`

Is there any way to get a more detailed report on the error event?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I usually connect via RDP to the affected node and do the following things in such a case:

- **Check Console-Out / Console-Error logs**: Service Fabric stores console output (if enabled via `<ConsoleRedirection>` in your `ServiceManifest.xml`) and errors in a log folder. On your DEV cluster, this should be `C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\Node.x\<ApplicationTypeFolder>\log`. On a default installation in Azure, it should be `D:\SvcFab\_App\<ApplicationTypeFolder>\log`
- **EventLog**: .NET exceptions sometimes show up in the "Application" log, but Service Fabric also has its own subfolder which might contain helpful events.
- **PerfView**: PerfView is a very powerful tool to monitor ETW events (Event Tracing for Windows). Since .NET exceptions are logged as ETW events, PerfView might show you helpful exceptions. Here's a quick tutorial:

  - Download and run [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/Downloading.md)
  - Go to "Collect -> Collect". De-Select "Merge".
  - Click "Start Collection".
  - Now kill your Service Fabric Service through Process Explorer, in case it is running. Moments later, Service Fabric will start it again.
  - If your service is not running, re-deploy your service.
  - After the service failed, press "Stop collection" in PerfView.
  - Now double-click on "Events" in the left tree - this will open all recorded ETW events.
  - Search for "Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/Exception/Start" and double click on it.
  - You should now see all .NET exceptions that occurred, ordered by time.