# Service fabric failure when deployed to Azure, but working locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

A stateless service made in Core 3.1 requires a Nuget package that is being problematic. If my csproj looks like the default of:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>True</ServerGarbageCollection>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>False</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Staging</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The application fails to run locally due to a System.BadImageFormatException: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)

Modifying the csproj to look like:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>True</ServerGarbageCollection>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>False</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Staging</Configurations>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Allows it to work correctly when deployed to my local cluster on my machine for testing.

Once deployed to Azure however, it's failing. I can't determine the source or error message. None of my logging is being invoked, so I assume it's failing at a very early point. Service Fabric Explorer is giving a very unhelpful, generic error message of There was an error during CodePackage activation.Container failed to start for image, exit code: 2147516547.

Why is local vs Azure behaving differently and is it possible to make some change to get Azure to work like the local cluster so that this runs?

Comment: Are the deployed and local Service Fabric versions the same? Are you deploying in the same configuration?

Comment: Actually no, Azure is 8.1.321.9590 and Local is 8.1.329.9590

Comment: I'm not seeing how I would upgrade or downgrade either to match though.

Comment: That's a pretty minor version change, that shouldn't affect it but it might be worth a try to upgrade just to be sure. Depending on how the fabric is deployed you can manually upgrade or you can redeploy the ARM.

Comment: In the portal, locate the cluster, left side > Fabric upgrades

Comment: Are you running the service inside a container? If so, did you follow the [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-services-inside-containers) to enable use of containerized services?

Comment: Can you try using a larger VM SKU inside Azure to see if your node isn't running out of memory?

Comment: You can check the logs using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887407/5946937) answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When the Azure DevOps pipeline deployed to ServiceFabric in Azure I had the error "There was an error during CodePackage activation.The process/container terminated with exit code:2147516547". [According to this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-code-package-errors#when-does-a-process-or-container-terminate-unexpectedly)"

> The exit code in this health message is the only clue that the process
> or container provides about why it terminated.

But it would work locally on my `ServiceFabric` cluster. The exit code led me to this StackOverflow page at which point I noticed that the "Platforms" node in my CSPROJ file was missing.